# Приведение типов в дженериках

Tags: c#, generics, cast

Есть у меня некоторый обобщённый класс, который делает Request и отдаёт Response:

```
public class WebService
{
    public TResponse Call<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request)
            where TRequest : RequestBase
            where TResponse : ResponseBase
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class ResponseBase
{
    public int RemoteStatus { get; set; }

    public bool Success
    {
        get { return this.RemoteStatus == SuccessStatusCode; }
    }

    public bool Fail
    {
        get { return this.RemoteStatus == FailedStatusCode; }
    }

    private const int SuccessStatusCode = 0;
    private const int FailedStatusCode = -1;
}
```

И при одном из рефакторингов я решил использовать имевшийся фабричный метод:

```
public static ResponseBase Failed()
{
    return new ResponseBase { RemoteStatus = FailedStatusCode };
}
```

И хотя такой код скомпилировался:

```
    return (TResponse)ResponseBase.Failed();
```

но в рантайме упал с ошибкой приведения типа:

> InvalidCastException: Не удалось привести тип объекта "ResponseBase" к типу "Response".

И я вот задумался: как наиболее простым способом у типа TResponse вызвать статический метод (добавлено: и как это будет соотноситься с отсутствием ограничения `new()`)?

Я немного покопался с рефлексией (`typeof(TResponse).GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static)`), но оказалось что в рантайме информация о том, что  TResponse = ResponseBase куда-то потерялась, уже `typeof(TResponse)` выдаёт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И добраться до .Failed() для того, чтобы дёрнуть `MethodInfo.Invoke` не получается.

Или это вообще тупиковое направление и я странного хочу? Я на текущий момент бросил эти попытки, добавив в ограничения `, new()` и прямо создав экземпляр класса TResponse -- но чисто академический интерес остался.

Comment: TResponse - это **НЕ** ResponseBase

Comment: Можешь более подробно описать где находится код, который не работает и что ты хотел получить?

Comment: @Grundy Неработающий код находится внутри Call, там перехватчик исключений, внутри как раз стоит логирование и возврат `return (TResponse)ResponseBase.Failed();`

Comment: то есть тело Call можно заменить на  `return (TResponse)ResponseBase.Failed();`?

Comment: Проблема заключается в попытке downcast, когда базовый класс пытаются привести к наследнику и падают из-за этого

Comment: Да, можно заменить - я как раз и делал когда в Linqpad'е крутил так и эдак скрипт.

Comment: Хорошо, а как-то обойти downcast можно или это не имеет смысла, т.к запрещено дизайном языка и даже если и получится, то будет некрасивый код?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100434/discussion-between-grundy-and-a-k).